# Obtener solo datos nuevos que se agreguen a firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Cómo recupero en tiempo real solo los datos que se van registrando como nuevos en mi database.

Según la documentación es `child_added` pero este se ejecuta aunque no exista ningún dato guardado y si existen datos previos los carga todos.

```
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').orderByChild('id').equalTo('jsstoni').on('child_added', function(snapshot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar un seguimiento de los elementos añadidos desde un determinado punto de referencia y sin obtener los registro previos, puedes utilizar `endAt()` y `limit()`, por ejemplo, para obtener el último registro:

```
// recuperar el ultimo registro de `ref`
ref.endAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

   //todos los registros despues del ultimo continuan para invocar esta funcion
   console.log(snapshot.name(), snapshot.val());

});
```

Otra opción puede ser utilizar `limitToLast()` y `limitToFirst()`, los cuales reemplazan a `limit()`.

```
// recuperar el ultimo registro de `ref`
ref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

   // todos los registros despues del ultimo continuan para invocar esta funcion
   console.log(snapshot.name(), snapshot.val());
   // obtener la ultima llave insertada
   console.log(snapshot.key());

});
```

Y por último te adjunto este enlace donde existen algunos códigos de ejemplo: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6383103

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes monitorear en tiempo real los nodos que espcifiques en tu base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('usuarios/registros');
commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
    var clave = data.key;
    var texto = data.val().nombre;
    var autor = data.val().email;
  });
```

en el ejemplo estamos monitoreando el nodo registros de usuarios y este nos traera la información de cada nuevo cambio que se de en dicho nodo, de igual manera podemos monitorear cuando hay nuevos registros o eliminaciones en dicho nodo, por ejemplo:

```
 //Si Agrego un nuevo Usuario
  commentsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    var clave = data.key;
    var texto = data.val().nombre;
    var autor = data.val().email;
  });

  //Si se elimina un usuario
  commentsRef.on('child_removed', function(data) {
    var clave = data.key;
  });
```